# After user removes application access to his LinkedIn profile, next OAuth2 reauthorization fails

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I'm using django application with python-social-auth responsible for integration with Linkedin OAuth2 API.

Linkedin returns 500 server error:

```
{
    "error":"server_error",
    "error_description":"the authorization server encountered an unexpected condition : Unable to retrieve access token"
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new LinkedIn app with OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs set to `http://localhost/complete/linkedin-oauth2/?`
2. Setup django app with python-social-auth module:

   ```
   SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = &lt;API key&gt;
   SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = &lt;Secret Key&gt;
   ```
3. Run Django server on port 80 and go to: `http://localhost/login/linkedin-oauth2/`
4. Go to **[Linkedin Settings](https://www.linkedin.com/settings/)**, choose *Groups, Companies & Applications* > *View your applications*, select your application name and submit *Remove*
5. Logout user from your Django app and start authentication again: `http://localhost/login/linkedin-oauth2/`

Comment: This is not an issue with python-social-auth, but with LinkedIn service instead, Check https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/32749#comment-32749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [discussion](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/authorization-server-encountered-unexpected-condition-unable-retrieve-access-token) about this issue on the LinkedIn forums.

Apparently this can happen if you move from OAuth1 to OAuth2.

The proposed remedy until they resolve the problem is to create a new authentication key for our applications.